I want to return the max value of a row and then return the header
I want to be able to return the maximum date of a row, but I want to return the heading of the column rather than the actual date.  But, I want it to write the heading instead of the date. For example, the first row I want a column that will say “Quit.” because it contains the max value of that row


In powerquery, add column .. custom column .. with formula
= let a = Record.FieldValues(_) in Record.FieldNames(_){List.PositionOf(a,List.Max(a))}


searching only specified columns
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
search = {"Column1","Column2","Column3"},
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each let a = Record.FieldValues(_) in Record.FieldNames(_){List.PositionOf(a,List.Max(Record.ToList(Record.SelectFields(_,search))))})
in #"Added Custom"


can you explain how to label my columns in the power query statement because I have more than 6 columns and only want to use those 6 in finding the heading

Well you didn't actually ask that, so how was anyone supposed to know?  Anyway, edited answer
